# Using a prime number for the size of a HashTable

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable

I've been reading through my textbook about HashTables, and it says to use a prime number for the size of an array when rehashing it, however it doesn't explain why. I've also Googled it and the best answer I've found was "for technical reasons", what are these reasons as to why prime numbers should be used for the size of a HashTable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the hash function. Specifically, picking a prime for the hashtable size may compensate for the fact that the hash function used is poor and often returns congruent hashes for values that occur naturally together during execution. A prime number for the size of the hashtable improves the chances that any “period” the hash function may have is **relatively prime** with the size of the hashtable.

If using an excellent hash function, such as a cryptographic hash function, you can use any hashtable size without worry. A power of two is cheap because the division becomes a bitmask.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that in java hashmap's size is power of 2 and that is because it helps
In equal distribution of elements over array. I think using prime number is also for the purpose of avoiding collision and to distribute elements equally. Bucket index is decided as hashcode%arraysize,
Now, if size is any composite number then there are more chances of collision.